# Function fills vector yet it becomes empty at some point.

Tags: c++, vector

I have encountered a strange problem. I am attempting to fill a vector with one function then output it with another. The vector appears empty even after the function has been called though, and I believe it is filling it correctly. Here is my code so far. The result is

"Enter the input file name in.txt
Search in vector
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  vector::_M_range_check
Aborted (core dumped)
"

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cassert>

    #include<vector>
    #include "ArrayUtilities.h"


    using namespace std;

    void fillArray(istream& io, std::vector<int> a, int& actualSize)
    {
       int temp,i=0;
       io>>temp;
       while (temp!=-999)
       {
       a.push_back(temp);
           io>>temp;
           i++;
       }

       actualSize=i;
    }



    void outputArray(ostream& os,
            std::vector<int> a,
            const int actualSize,
            const string& info )
    {
os<<info<<"\n";
for (int w=0;w<actualSize;++w)
{
    os<< a.at(w)<<" ";

}
os<<"\n";
}
```

int main()
{

```
int actualSize;
string fileName;
string info;


std::vector<int> a;
cout << "Enter the input file name ";
cin  >> fileName;
ifstream inData;
ofstream outData;
inData.open(fileName.c_str());
outData.open("out.txt");
int searchItem;
inData>>info;
inData>>searchItem;
fillArray  (inData,  a, actualSize);
cout   <<"Search in vector\n";
outData<<"Search in vector\n";
    outputArray(outData, a, actualSize, info);
outputArray(cout,    a, actualSize, info);
//sequential search
int position;
position=seqSearch(a,actualSize,searchItem);
if (position > 0)
    {
        cout    << "Sequential Search: SearchItem "
                << searchItem
                << " is on position "
                << position
                << "\n";
        outData << "Sequential Search: SearchItem "
                << searchItem
                << " is on position "
                << position
                << "\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout    << "Sequential Search: SearchItem "
                << searchItem
                << " is not in the list\n";
        outData << "Sequential Search: SearchItem "
                << searchItem
                << " is not in the list\n";
    }
```

thank you for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function has a local copy of the vector. It doesn't affect the vector that is passed as argument. You can fix this by passing a reference to vector:

```
void fillArray(istream& io, std::vector<int>& a, int& actualSize)
//                                          ^
```

Answer (score 0):

juanchopanza showed the bug in your code.
I would recomend a different style.

Change fillArray to:

```
std::vector<int> fillArray(istream& io)
{
   std::vector<int> response;
   int temp;
   io>>temp;
   while (temp!=-999) {
       response.push_back(temp);
       io>>temp;
   }
   return response;
}
```

Used in main:

```
int main()
{
    int actualSize;
    string fileName;
    string info;

    std::vector<int> a;
    cout << "Enter the input file name ";
    cin  >> fileName;
    ifstream inData;
    ofstream outData;
    inData.open(fileName.c_str());
    outData.open("out.txt");
    int searchItem;
    inData>>info;
    inData>>searchItem;
    a = fillArray(inData);
    // If you really like actualSize add
    actualSize = a.size();
    cout   <<"Search in vector\n";
    outData<<"Search in vector\n";
        outputArray(outData, a, a.size(), info);
    ...
}
```

Natuarally I find it easier to read.
According to this talk by [Chandler Carruth](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eR34r7HOU14) easier to optimize.